# How hard would it be to state P vs. NP in a proof assistant?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np, proof-assistants

[GJ Woeginger lists 116 invalid proofs of P vs. NP problem](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Egwoegi/P-versus-NP.htm). Scott Aaronson published "[Eight Signs A Claimed P≠NP Proof Is Wrong](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=458)" to reduce hype each time someone attempts to settle P vs. NP. Some researchers even [refuse to proof-read papers settling the "P versus NP" question](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/p-vs-np.html).

I have 3 related questions:

1. Why are people not using proof assistants that could verify whether a proof of P vs. NP is correct?
2. How hard or how much effort would it be to state P vs. NP in a proof assistant in the first place?
3. Is there currently any software that would be at least in principle capable of verifying a P vs. NP proof?

Comment: Proof assistants are impractical currently. They require a huge amount of effort and expertise to use.

Comment: Also, in principle, there are software that can find proofs to every provable statement: the possible proofs are enumerable and can be checked, so it suffices to iteratively check each candidate proof until a valid proof is found.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I won't say they're _easy_ to use – proving stuff in Coq tends to take me 3× - 10× as long as proving it by hand. But “impractical” is a bit of an overstatement. Really the problem isn't so much that the assistants are impractical, but that they force you to make all the annoying technical-detail assumptions explicit that we otherwise tend to take for granted unquestioningly.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156975/solving-p-vs-np-with-computer

Comment: Many "proofs" contain bits that are so bad, they are not even wrong. You read it, and then you say "WTF"? That's where conversion to a proof assistant stops.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes, but for me that's actually a big part of the reason to push for assistant-formalization: it forces those pseudoproofs to be either replaced with proper rigorous ones. Even if that doesn't succeed everywhere, it's still useful: when reading a proof, you will be able to keep “I'm too stupid to understand this ingenious proof” apart from “well, that proof really is a bit fishy”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It doesn't force the author to do anything. They didn't do the work to arrange the proof for a proof assistant. Their argument will be "my proof is so elegant and clever, that's why you don't understand how to state it in a proof assistant".

Comment: To be slightly pedantic, if a verification software is capable of verifying a $P\ne NP$ proof, even in principle, then this implies that $P\ne NP$ is provable, and similarly for $P=NP$. So the answer to (3) is we don't know yet because we haven't proved P vs NP yet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with DW. I think that it is possible (although difficult) for a P vs. NP result to be stated in a proof assistant, and moreover, I wouldn't trust any supposed proofs unless they were formalized in this way, unless they came from *very* reputable sources.

In particular, none of the resources DW states are based on type theory, which is a very promising direction for proof assistants. Coq has been used to [formalize the proof of the 4-color theorem](https://github.com/math-comp/fourcolor) among others, so it's clearly capable of some heavy mathematical lifting.

To answer your specific questions:

1. The main reason is that theorem provers aren't widely accepted in the mathematical community. Learning them takes effort, and mathematicians are often skeptical of the underlying techniques (type theory, constructive math, etc.)
   But there are some fields where leading researchers are very comfortable with making large developments formalized in a proof assistant, like category theory, programming language theory, formal logic, etc. So I think there is as much of a cultural issue as an inherent feasibility issue.

   The other reason is that, so far, most of the purported "proofs" have been by cranks, who don't want to formalize their result because it will inevitably reveal the flaws.
2. It is not hard at all to state P vs. NP in a proof assistant. One could use Turing Machines, but it would probably be easier to model a simple Turing-complete programming language using inductive families to model small-step semantics, and define the run-time as the number of steps a program takes. You could define $P$ as the languages accepted by programs halting in a polynomial number of steps, and $NP$ as languages that can be verified in polytime with a polynomial-length certificate.

   EDIT: It turns out [there are existing techniques](https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/%7Emoyen/walgo/papers/FHMMN-Coq.pdf) for showing that algorithms run in polynomial time in a theorem prover. So this could be used either to show a polytime algorithm for an NP-hard problem, or to derive a contradiction from the existence of such an algorithm.
3. There is *tons* of software that is capable of verifying such a proof, *provided the proof was written using that software*. The two candidates I'd put the most stock in are [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) and [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/about/). Coq in particular has been used to verify several major results in mathematics.

Comment: Why might the involvement of type theory help? Is it because it allows for more efficient automated strategies/tactics?

Comment: The last paragraph of (1) is the right answer. Most presumptive proofs are by cranks and a simple test of their crankyness serve as test and is more cost effective. When an argument appears that passes sufficient revisions by experts, I am sure many will be motivated to formalize and verify it automatically.

Comment: Funny choice of example; the four color theorem is true for certain well-behavedness assumptions but false in general.

Comment: What do you think of the argument made in my answer that it's likely any proof will rely on lots of prior results, and you'd first have to formalize everything that the paper relies on (every result taught in an undergraduate or graduate course on CS theory, every prior paper that is implicitly relied upon, etc.), and that might take many person-years to do?

Comment: "aren't widely accepted in the mathematical community"? Maybe you mean that they aren't widely used. Otherwise, says who? "cultural issue"? That reminds me of Harvey Friedman who is always complaining of things like that. I have never seen anything like that. Instead, there is pragmatism. The resources to use, the time to learn, and the payoff of using them don't always exist. "mathematicians are often skeptical of the underlying techniques"? Not of the underlying techniques, but of the implementation and as much as one is skeptical of a peer reviewed informal proof.

Comment: @D.W. Changed it, I think.

Comment: @plop, thank you.  I appreciate the change.  What is the purpose of the comparison to Harvey Friedman?   Does that contribute evidence or reasoning  to the argument one way or another?  I don't know who he is, so I'm not sure how that applies.

Comment: @LukaMikec There's a bunch of advantages to using type theory. The main one is that it allows the logic to be computational: determining if two things are (definitionally) equal is a mechanical process that the proof assistant can do automatically. it also combines programming and proving via the Curry-Howard Isomorphism, so writing programs that generate proofs basically turns into programming with higher-order functions. Finally, it makes things much easier to define, i.e. defining natural numbers or other inductive sets is dead easy, and you get induction principles for free.

Comment: @Joshua This is news to me, do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @D.W. You're right of course that this is a lot of work, but given the volume of incorrect attempts that draw on this work to varying degrees, I thing there's great value to work that formalizes this theory, so the eventual proof one way or the other (or the proof that it's independent of a particular logical system) can be trusted.

Comment: @jmite: It was in a Scientific American circa 2003 or so. The contrary case involved a border line defined by y = sin (1/x) as well as two more border lines going through the origin and the fifth being a box around the whole thing. The actual origin of the problem is political borders, for which we need 5 colors only because ocean can't be reused for landlocked countries, but that's an accident as countries are not contiguous. Historically, they've also been three-dimensionally complex but no examples exist today.

Comment: @Joshua So it still applies to all planar graphs, but it's just that not all maps can be represented by planar graphs?

Comment: @jmite: Ah; the theorem is proved on the nodes of the graph being 4-colorable not the regions between the edges, so the non well-formed cases all can't be converted to planar graphs.

Comment: @Joshua That's because the theorem is stated for that case. Real-life exceptions such as exclaves, Moon colonies, distinctive water colouring, a higher-genus planet, etc. are excluded from the formulation of the theorem because it is quite obvious that these features introduce counterexamples

Comment: @D.W.: There's nothing stopping you from formally proving a theorem of the form "if X,...,Y hold then P≠NP" where X,...,Y are previously published theorems. So your 'argument' that you would have to formalize all prior knowledge that the proof relies on does not hold water. If really such a formal proof is found by anyone, it would be *much easier* for experts to check whether X,...,Y are indeed correct than to check a convoluted poof. The whole point is *not* to formalize all needed mathematical knowledge but *just* the part that people most need verification of.

Comment: @user21820, ahh, good point!  So you'd still have to formalize the *statement* of all prior results you're relying on, but not the *proof* of them.  Excellent point, thank you, that had not occurred to me.

Comment: You don't need "EDIT" tags when you edit, it's only confusing to people who come to your post for the first time like me :-) But a nice answer!

Comment: @user21820 So if X, ..., Y were all assumed to be proven theorems, and together they imply P = NP or P ≠ NP, then quite likely one of them is unexpectedly not correct.

Comment: @gnasher729: Or, the foundational system used to prove X,...,Y is inconsistent. Sure, but whatever happens we will learn something significant, which wouldn't happen so easily if the purported proof of (X∧...∧Y)⇒(P=NP) is a hundred pages of convoluted statements. In particular, we might endlessly look for a mistake in those hundred pages even if the mistake was in X,...,Y.

Answer (score 10):

Using proof assistants for this purpose is certainly possible in principle, but I suspect it would take more effort than most folks who write such proofs would be interested in putting in.  It would require a substantial amount of effort from the author of a purported P vs NP proof to formalize their proof.

Translating a proof written for humans into a format that a proof assistant can verify was tedious and time-consuming.  I have seen estimates of between a day to a week of effort per page of human-written proof.  Then, one must also formalize all prior results that the proof is building on.  When we look at recent attempts at proving P vs NP, they typically use a lot of advanced machinery and sophisticated pre-existing results from prior papers, which would need to be formalized too.

Because of this, I expect it would be completely impractical to formalize both the proposed new proof and the proofs of all prior results that it relies upon, for the kinds of purported proofs we've seen so far.  As [user21820 points out](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128841/how-hard-would-it-be-to-state-p-vs-np-in-a-proof-assistant/128849?noredirect=1#comment270379_128849), what would be more practical would be to formalize only the statement of all prior results that are relied upon, but not their proof.  Thus, instead of proving the theorem $T$, we'd formalize a proof that $(X \land Y \land \cdots) \implies T$, where $X,Y,\dots$ are the prior results that the proof relies upon.  This falls short of fully verifying the NP-completeness result, but if people have faith in the prior results, it would allow people to gain confidence in the new result.  This would be a lot more realistic than formalizing the entire proof of $T$: while it would take some effort to formalize all of the prior results $X,Y,\dots$, it's a lot less than the effort to formalize the proofs of those prior results too.

Still, it would be challenging and require a non-trivial expenditure of effort to formalize a proof, even with this trick.

You can look at existing libraries of theorems in mathematics and computer science that have been formalized and formally verified: see http://us.metamath.org/ and http://formalmath.org/ and https://www.isa-afp.org/topics.html and http://mizar.org/library/.  You might notice that a lot of what is formalized there concerns basic undergraduate material.  We're a far way from formalizing all theorems taught at an undergraduate level, let alone those taught at a graduate level, let alone new research results.

For more background, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/792010/14578 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113316/14578 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1767070/14578 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2747661/14578 and http://www.ams.org/notices/200811/tx081101370p.pdf.

Comment: If we have a P algorithm (i.e. of SAT), we can use proof asst. to prove it's correctness (by induction?). Wouldn't it be an equivalent to verifying a P vs NP proof with a proof asst.?

Comment: @ABD, good point.  Possibly -- if the proofs is a proof of P=NP (this doesn't help for P$\ne$NP), and if the proof works by exhibiting a polynomial-time algorithm for some NP-complete problem (this doesn't help if it is a non-constructive proof), and if the proof of correctness for this algorithm is simple.  I suspect that any such algorithm will require a non-trivial proof of correctness, in which case we are back to square one, and the comments in my answer apply.

Comment: "about a day of effort per page of human-written proof". That would be a fairly standard parsing speed for a human in many fields.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys, sure, but see my point about having to first formalize all of the tens of thousands of prior results that the new paper relies on.  (Also see the comment about another study suggesting the cost might be more like a week per page.)

Comment: Thanks for updating your post! By the way, one more reason to formalize known or new mathematics in such conditional theorem form is that it makes it modular. As I am sure you know, modularity means that you can focus your attention on a part that you want to without having to look at other parts. This is why there are many results of the form ( RH ⇒ Q ) where RH is Riemann's hypothesis. Despite RH not being proven yet, these results actually lend weight to the importance of focusing on RH. Of course we hope not to find ¬RH in the end. =)

Answer (score 9):

I can give a direct answer to (2): $P\ne NP$ [has been stated](https://github.com/formalabstracts/formalabstracts/blob/e547f5939875ac6677b01ec6086d40992fa92629/fabstract/Cook_S_P_NP/fabstract.lean#L81) in Lean (along with the other main results of Cook's paper, where the conjecture was first described), as part of the [Formal Abstracts](https://formalabstracts.github.io/) project.

Comment: Has any one tried `by auto`?

Answer (score 4):

I believe your question is not that much of a proper theory question, so with your permission I'll give it a not-so-technical answer.

> Why are people not using proof assistants that could verify whether a proof of P vs. NP is correct?

Because CS theorists rarely (perhaps extremely rarely) write proofs in machine-verifiable form.

> How hard or how much effort would it be to state P vs. NP in a proof assistant in the first place?

Very hard at least in the "uninteresting" sense that @DW explained; but it could be anywhere from easy to impossible in the "interesting" sense of expressing the concepts in a proof, if it were to exist.

But you know, this will never happen because:

1. Until a proof is found it can't be done anyway
2. You have to know the proof like the back of your hand to convert it into machine-verifiable form.
3. ... and when enough people know the proof, they will either have found a flaw or be satisfied that it's valid and not care about machine-checking it.

> Is there currently any software that would be at least in principle capable of verifying a P vs. NP proof?

I'm not well-versed enough in proof verification software to comment about what's actually implemented, but it's probably nearly-impossible to answer your question, because - who knows what form such a proof will take? And thus - how would you know, now, if it's expressible in such a way that your proof verifier can process?

Comment: We could ask whether Wiles' proof for Fermat's Last Theorem can be verified by any software. I know it can't be verified by me :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 From http://www.cs.rug.nl/~wim/fermat/wilesEnglish.html: "I expect the problem [of verifying a proof of FLT] to be solved in around fifty years, with a very wide margin. On this page, I try to explain some aspects of the problem, and to give relevant links to the literature and to other web pages."

Comment: "In the spirit of a long and strong Dutch tradition." <-- !!